# Replacing numeric elements by equal index

Tags: r, indexing

I have a big dataframe `dim(13265x40)`. The dataframe was created by combining several seperate dataframes in a list by:
`big_dataframe = bind_rows(dataframe_list, .id = "Index")`.
`.id = "Index"` gave me an additional column called `"Index"` with a numeric input (1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) so I still can identify the seperate dataframes in the `big_dataframe`.

Example:

```
big_dataframe:
Index  A  B  C  D
1      3  6  7  1
1      6  6  2  0
1      7  5  4  2
2      4  0  7  4
2      3  2  9  1
2      9  4  4  5
3      7  1  5  2
3      3  9  3  4
3      1  1  2  10
4      10 6  7  1
```

and so on.
Then i have an indexlist: `indexlist = c("John", "Peter", "Michael", "Brian", etc.)` which contains `"character"` elements.

The goal would be, to replace the numeric input in `big_dataframe$Index` by the element of `indexlist` with the equal index.
Example:

```
big_dataframe:
Index  A  B  C  D
John   3  6  7  1
John   6  6  2  0
John   7  5  4  2
Peter  4  0  7  4
Peter  3  2  9  1
Peter  9  4  4  5
Peter  7  1  5  2
Peter  3  9  3  4
Peter  1  1  2  10
Brian  10 6  7  1
```

I am a bit lost for this an don't know how I could approach this problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Baseed on your input dataset, why the 3 in 'Index' is replaced by 'Peter'.  Should that be 'Michael'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'index' is numeric and as it is starting from 1, it can be used as a index of replacing the values with 'indexlist' value in the same order

```
big_dataframe$Index <- indexlist[big_dataframe$Index]
```

#### data

```
big_dataframe <- structure(list(Index = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L), A = c(3L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 10L), B = c(6L, 
6L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 6L), C = c(7L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L), D = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

indexlist <- c("John", "Peter", "Michael", "Brian")
```

Comment: This actually gives me for all elements in```big_dataframe$Index``` ```NA```.

Comment: @Mcgroger the case matters `big_dataframe$Index`, earlier i used `big_dataframe$index` can you check now.  if that doesn't work, can you check whether the `Index` column is `numeric` class or not

Comment: ```class(dfl_combined$Index) = "character"```
So that probably the issue.

Comment: @Mcgroger In that case, just change to `indexlist[as.integer(big_dataframe$Index)]`